# SAML authnresponse binding

Tags: saml-2.0

Does anybody know if the SAML2 AuthnResponse can be send with the HTTP-REDIRECT binding? I only found examples for AuthnRequests using the HTTP-REDIRECT binding.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. For SAML 2.0 Web SSO, you cannot use HTTP-Redirect Binding for the AuthnResponse. Your only valid Bindings are HTTP-POST or HTTP-Artifact.

Page 6 of the SAML 2.0 Conformance doc outlines the valid bindings for various scenarios-- http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-conformance-2.0-os.pdf

Answer (score 0):

No, a SAML AuthnResponse MUST NOT be sent using the HTTP Redirect binding, see http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf#page=16 which says:

> Identity Provider issues to Service Provider In step 5, the identity
>   provider issues a message to be delivered by the user agent to the
>   service provider. Either the HTTP POST, or HTTP Artifact binding can
>   be used to transfer the message to the service provider through the
>   user agent. The message may indicate an error, or will include (at
>   least) an authentication assertion. The HTTP Redirect binding MUST NOT
>   be used, as the response will typically exceed the URL length
>   permitted by most user agents.